# About the verification Exception in c#

Tags: c#, exception, system.drawing

I'm currently working on a PS Vita project in which i need to use **System.Drawing.dll**.
Although I added **System.Drawing.dll** to the reference, when i initializes an **rectangle** instance it gives me a **VerificationException** error. 
My question is, how to make my program work.

Thank You

Comment: How did you add the reference?  Are you directly referencing the DLL or did you add it as an assembly reference via the framework?  Also, show the code that's throwing the exception, maybe there's something else going on.

Answer (score 1):

Try [PEVerify Tool (Peverify.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62bwd2yd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). It is a command line utility that verifies that the IL in an assembly is type safe in a particular runtime environment.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.verificationexception.aspx) for `VerificationException`:

> The exception that is thrown when the security policy requires code to be type safe and the verification process is unable to verify that the code is type safe.

`System.Drawing` uses GDI+, which requires calling native methods. This may be the reason for the exception. Take another look at the documentation for PS Vita and verify which libraries you can use with it.